# colinux related queries are off the topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

As Title
"colinux related queries are off the topic?"

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it is related as whole *nix system is running.

I'd vote for inclusion of cygwin (but not mingw) and Windows Services for UNIX.

Comment: unless it's mingw as it pertains to msys

Answer (score 2):

colinux questions seem fine. Fedora, Debian, Ubuntu, etc. running on colinux are very similar to Fedora, Debian, Ubuntu, etc. running on a 'regular' system. Most of the questions will be the same.

I don't totally understand how coLinux works (I ran it for a few months) and I guess some of the more technical questions (Regarding the Cooperative Virtual Machine layer between the Linux kernel and the hardware) might not be a perfect fit, but this site should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to venture that questions about how coLinux integrates with the NT kernel would be best asked elsewhere (I'm not exactly sure *where*), as would many other Windows-side questions about coLinux, but of course the entire Linux userspace used would be on-topic, as would some aspects of using the kernel, and the line probably gets fuzzy in the middle there somewhere (though I expect only those at least somewhat conversant with both NT-driver- and Linux-kernel- hacking would have much to say about that part)...