# Cygwin on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should we consider [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) on-topic here? It's similar to a Linux command-line and has many of the same tools, so lots of answers will probably just be the same as if the user was on Linux. However, it also has quirks and oddities that are cygwin-specific; there was an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855125/problem-using-sudo-on-cygwin) recently that wouldn't have happened on a normal Linux install

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Certainly just because you're using the Cygwin version of [vi](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309/are-questions-about-vi-vim-and-other-clones-on-topic-here) or bash doesn't make a question about regexp replacement or brace expansion off-topic.

When it comes to questions that are more directly tied to a particular implementation, it seems to me that since we allow questions about interactions between Unix implementations and hardware, we should also allow questions about interactions between Unix implementations such as Cygwin, GNUWin32, [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) (Ubuntu on Windows, Bash on Windows), [coLinux](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/colinux-related-queries-are-off-the-topic), etc. and the underlying platform.

However, if a question is essentially on the Windows side and the fact that Cygwin is a Unix implementation is completely incidental (e.g. [`cygwin1.dll` woes](https://superuser.com/questions/194529/cygwin-fatal-error-unable-to-remap-what-does-it-mean)), I think it should be asked on a [Windows site](https://superuser.com/), because I don't expect that there is much expertise about Windows on this site.

As for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855125/problem-using-sudo-on-cygwin), the asker doesn't even know what Linux is. I think it would fare better on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). I'm not sure that the asker even should have been using Cygwin in the first place.

Comment: I have no problems asking about bugs in the implementation... though answering "bug" is also find with me. How'm I supposed to know if it's a bug in my code, or my unix implementation? what if it behaves differently on bsd, linux, aix, and cygwin ... and the cygwin behavior is a bug... well who'd have guessed? should wine users ask here or on superuser?

Comment: Huh, [su] is Windows site?! It's more that it's a site including but not limited to Windows-specific problems.

Answer (score 4):

Cygwin is a POSIX compatibility layer (and a little more, and a little less) on Windows. So it is *nix sort-of friendly. Therefore I would consider it on topic, with the provisions that Gilles makes.

Answer (score 2):

I would say in the general case no, but the Pee-Wee Herman rule applies.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/the-pee-wee-herman-rule/

If the asker appears smart and groks UNIX conventions and asks "the right way" it *can be OK in some circumstances*, as they would be an asset to the community.

Answer (score 1):

I assume Cygwin is not Linux, but I assume it's Unix (or at least Not Unix (tm)).